# How can I solve "Input string was not in correct format"

Tags: c#

Its one of my first projekts, and its even copied off a Danish beginner book, I have double checked serval times, and they're identical, but there still seems to be an error.

```
using System;

namespace Amount_and_price
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write the price here  ");
            String text = Console.ReadLine();
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(text);
            Console.WriteLine("Write the amount here   ");
            text = Console.ReadLine();
            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(text);
            double amount = price * quantity;
            double vat = amount * 0.25;
            double total = amount + vat;
            Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} { 1, 10:F}", "Pris på varen", price);
            Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} { 1, 10:D}", "Antal styk", quantity);
            Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} { 1, 10:F}", "Pris eks. moms", amount);
            Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} { 1, 10:F}", "Moms", vat);
            Console.WriteLine("{0  -15} { 1, 10:F}", "Total pris, inkl. moms", total);

        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to change so the error "Input string was not in correct format" doesn't appear?

Comment: where does the error appear? i guess it is on the `Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: or `Convert.ToInt32(text)`

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Writeline gives error I guess.

Comment: I have no red underline in the code, it does mention something about line 22:  Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} { 1, 10:F}", "Pris på varen", price); the error comes up after I write "the amount" and press enter

Comment: Do know you're not the first to encounter this [particular error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CInput+string+was+not+in+correct+format%E2%80%9D). Don't forget to use the [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I have tried with different types of nummbers, like 11 and 11,95

Comment: You seriously need to stop coding and grab a copy of CLR Via C#.  Skip the chapters on the garbage collector and the common language runtime and start learning how the language works.  Once you're through reading the book you will have a very good grasp on the language and can actually ask questions that won't get downvoted.  Possibly.  Also, don't ask programming questions on Meta, that's for discussion of this website only.

Comment: I'll take your advice and do that, thanks. I don't feel like this book is explaining things very well anyhow. - yea I deleted my post again on Meta, figured it was the wrong place.

Comment: @will I'd really like to ask you a question or two if you don't mind. I looked at the book but it seems I don't have the experience according to the reviews. I have only been reading about c# for about a month. I was hoping you could give an advice on a good beginners book, learning about C# and .net, since there seem to be so many different.

Comment: I strongly suggest that book.  I just viewed the table of contents on Amazon, you should start reading at chapter 4.  It starts very low level with objects and structs, and then builds on the syntax from that point.  You can always return and read the other chapters once you feel comfortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have spaces between the opening brace and the argument number in your `Console.WriteLine` statement. All your Console.WriteLine statements need to be modified with this change. Below is an illustrative line to explain the change

Wrong Code

```
Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} { 1, 10:F}", "Pris på varen", price);
```

Right Code

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,10:F}", "Pris på varen", price);
```

Also your last `Console.WriteLine` statement has a missing comma (as pointed out by @Berkay

Wrong Code

```
Console.WriteLine("{0  -15} {1, 10:F}", "Total pris, inkl. moms", total);
```

Right code

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-15} {1,10:F}", "Total pris, inkl. moms", total);
```

Comment: And also last `Console.WriteLine` has a missing **","**.

Comment: Edit: it did work afterall, my bad. And thanks again :)!

Comment: Thanks @Berkay I have updated the answer with that change

Answer (score 0):

Spaces, commas missing where needed. You can share the https://dotnetfiddle.net/z8q1he . It would be easy for people to play around with your code.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write the price here  ");
        String text = Console.ReadLine();
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(text);
        Console.WriteLine("Write the amount here   ");
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(text);
        double amount = price * quantity;
        double vat = amount * 0.25;
        double total = amount + vat;
        Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} {1, 10:F}", "Pris pa varen", price);
        Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} {1, 10:D}", "Antal styk", quantity);
        Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} {1, 10:F}", "Pris eks. moms", amount);
        Console.WriteLine("{0, -15} {1, 10:F}", "Moms", vat);
        Console.WriteLine("{0,  -15} {1, 10:F}", "Total pris inkl. moms", total);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested a lot, I would say the line:
double price = Convert.ToDouble(text);
is also dangerous, as it would be hard to know if it is expecting comma or period as decimal seperator - and that would give the exact error, so try using an int, og try both comma and period to test if there is a difference...
And consider handling it by setting the culture of the thread

Answer (score -1):

You had some syntax errors in the code. The last `Console.WriteLine` method calls are using a string formatting structure but are missing `string.Format()`. In addition, The last line is missing a comma between the numeric values of the first parentheses. Anyway, here's the corrected code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Write the price here  ");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(text);
        Console.WriteLine("Write the amount here   ");
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(text);
        double amount = price * quantity;
        double vat = amount * 0.25;
        double total = amount + vat;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -15} {1, 10:F}", "Pris på varen", price));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -15} {1, 10:D}", "Antal styk", quantity));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -15} {1, 10:F}", "Pris eks. moms", amount));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -15} {1, 10:F}", "Moms", vat));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0, -15} {1, 10:F}", "Total pris, inkl. moms", total));
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: I don't think you can call it a "syntax error". Syntax errors are those that don't let the program compile successfully. Basically, the OP wrote some statements that caused a runtime error.

Comment: WriteLine has overloads that accept a format string and params.

Comment: And there is a [`Console.WriteLine(String, params Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload that understands `String.Format()` format strings.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes but my corrections clearly fixed his code and the missing comma is clearly a syntax error or however you want to call it (english is not my native language).

Comment: @Innat3 Just to clarify, I downvoted because `Console.WriteLine` contains an overload that works like a `string.Format`, as Phylogenesis mentioned.